# #!/usr/bin/php sometimes not working on 12.10 server

Tags: php

I've recently moved some working code from a 12.04 server to a 12.1 server.
Everything working well except....

Some of my scripts include
`#!/usr/bin/php -q` 
at the top so I can run them from the command line without explicitly invoking php/.

Some of these work find, some others do not work at all - 
I get the error message:

```
Exception: Zend Extension ./makeTracks.php does not exist
```

There is a correct link from `/usr/bin/php` to `etc/alternatives/php` and then on to `/usr/bin/php5`

I don't know if something changed between 12.04 and 12.10 that is causing this or what else might cause it.  I'm stumped.

Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 11):

It turned out that this problem was caused by php files that has been uploaded with Windows line endings.  Once I corrected the line endings using dos2unix the problem went away.

Comment: This answer needs 100 more up votes. This is incredibly obscure and was hard for me to find, but a perfect answer.

Comment: Debian Jessie and this still works! +1

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks a million times ... I've been working on this for more than 24 hours +1000000